# Filtering array of custom objects

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I had a class which is not a subclass of `NSObject` and an array of instances of that class.

```
enum ObjectType{
  case type1
  case type2
  case type3  
}

class MyObject {
  var type = ObjectType!
  //some other properties...
}

let array = [obj1(type:type1),
             obj2(type:type2),
             obj3(type:type3),
             obj4(type:type2),
             obj5(type:type3)]

let type2Array = array.filter(){ $0.type == .type2}
// type2Array is supposed to be [obj2, obj4]
```

this is causing `fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C`

How can I filter array appropriately?

Do I have to subclass from `NSObject` or make my class conform to any protocol?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7.3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I can see from your question, none of the above really has any connection to Objective-C. Your example contains a few other issues, however, keeping it from working as intended.

- `MyObject` has no initializer (as of Swift 2.2, you should include at least one initializer).
- What are `obj1`, `obj2`, ... ? You treat these as methods or *class/structures types*, when I presume you're intending for these to be *instances* of the `MyObject` type.

If fixing the above, the actual filtering part of your code will work as intended (note that you can omit `()` from `filter() {... }`), e.g.:

```
enum ObjectType{
    case type1
    case type2
    case type3
}

class MyObject {
    var type : ObjectType
    let id: Int
    init(type: ObjectType, id: Int) {
        self.type = type
        self.id = id
    }
}

let array = [MyObject(type: .type1, id: 1),
             MyObject(type: .type2, id: 2),
             MyObject(type: .type3, id: 3),
             MyObject(type: .type2, id: 4),
             MyObject(type: .type3, id: 5)]

let type2Array = array.filter { $0.type == .type2}
type2Array.forEach { print($0.id) } // 2, 4
```

---

As an alternative to filtering directly to an enumeration case, you could specify the `rawValue` type of your enumeration and match to this instead. E.g. using an `Int` `rawValue` allows you to (in addition to filtering w.r.t. `rawValue`) perform pattern matching for say, ranges of cases in your enumeration.

```
enum ObjectType : Int {
    case type1 = 1  // rawValue = 1
    case type2      // rawValue = 2, implicitly
    case type3      // ...
}

class MyObject {
    var type : ObjectType
    let id: Int
    init(type: ObjectType, id: Int) {
        self.type = type
        self.id = id
    }
}

let array = [MyObject(type: .type1, id: 1),
             MyObject(type: .type2, id: 2),
             MyObject(type: .type3, id: 3),
             MyObject(type: .type2, id: 4),
             MyObject(type: .type3, id: 5)]

/* filter w.r.t. to rawValue */
let type2Array = array.filter { $0.type.rawValue == 2}
type2Array.forEach { print($0.id) } // 2, 4

/* filter using pattern matching, for rawValues in range [1,2],
   <=> filter true for cases .type1 and .type2 */
let type1or2Array = array.filter { 1...2 ~= $0.type.rawValue }
type1or2Array.forEach { print($0.id) } // 1, 2, 4
```

Comment: Is it required to have init in a custom class? How about `let object1 = MyObject; object1.id = 1; object1.type = type1 ...`?