# How to find matches of certain properties in a set of struct instances?

Tags: swift, struct

I'm experimenting with structs in Swift 3 and trying to extract/print some values. Here's my code:

```
struct person {
    var name: String
    var gender: String
    var age: Int
}

var people = [
    person(
        name: "Steve",
        gender: "Male",
        age: 25
    ),
    person(
        name: "Paul",
        gender: "Male",
        age: 30
    ),
    person(
        name: "Sandra",
        gender: "Female",
        age: 21
    ),
    person(
        name: "Becky",
        gender: "Female",
        age: 30
    ),
    person(
        name: "Trevor",
        gender: "Male",
        age: 45
    )
]
```

I've learned that I can find the `age` of a person if I supply the `name`:

```
let nameToSearch = "Trevor"

if let i = people.index(where: {$0.name == nameToSearch}) {
    print("\(nameToSearch) is aged \(people[i].age)") // Trevor is aged 45
}
```

What is the best way to...

1) Capture the four oldest people in the group, sort them into descending order by age, and print them like this?

```
Trevor is aged 45
Paul is aged 30
Becky is aged 30
Steve is aged 25
```

2) Capture all instances where the `gender` is `"Male"`, and print them like this?

```
The males are Steve, Paul, Trevor
```

And out of interest, assuming that the user was performing actions that led to getting/setting existing instances, as well as adding/removing instances, is there a rough number of `person` instances in the `people` array that would cause app performance to take a hit?

Comment: Note that a simpler way of getting the first element in a sequence that satisfies a given predicate would be using `first(where:)` – e.g `if let person = people.first(where: {$0.name == nameToSearch}) {...}`

Comment: For your first question, see [How can I find the highest elements of an Array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36960520/2976878). For your second question, see [Filtering array of custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36260439/2976878). I would recommend that you implement the `gender` property as a custom `Gender` enum rather than using a `String` btw.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated. I'll look into custom enums next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A succinct way to get the 4 oldest people:

```
let oldestPeople = people.sorted(by: { $0.0.age > $0.1.age })[0 ..< 4]
for person in oldestPeople {
    print("\(person.name) is aged \(person.age)")
}
```

And to get the male names:

```
let maleNames = people.filter({ $0.gender == "Male" }).map({ $0.name })
print("The males are " + maleNames.joined(separator: ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for steering me in the right direction Hamish. Here are my solutions. To get the four oldest people:

```
var personAndAge = [String: Int]()

people.forEach {
    personAndAge[$0.name] = $0.age
}

var increment = 0
let limit = 4

for (person, age) in personAndAge.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 }) {
    increment = increment + 1
    if (increment <= limit) {
        print("\(person) is aged \(age)")
    }
}

/*
prints:
Trevor is aged 45
Becky is aged 30
Paul is aged 30
Steve is aged 25
*/
```

To get the males only:

```
let peopleFilteredToMales = people.filter { $0.gender == "Male"}
var maleNames: [String] = []
peopleFilteredToMales.forEach { maleNames.append($0.name) }
let outputString = "The males are " + maleNames.joined(separator: ", ")
print(outputString)

// prints: The males are Steve, Paul, Trevor
```